# Framerate limited by lack of mouse movement?

Tags: opengl, mouse, frame-rate, torque

Using Torque, it appears that the program is running at around 25fps when the mouse is still, but as long as I keep the mouse moving, the framerate can hit well over 300fps. What in the world would cause the framerate to be tied to mouse movement?

Comment: Does the same happen if something else is moving on the screen? Maybe the engine lowers the framerate when it doesn't need to render anything.

Comment: Does that happen "out of the box"? Could you provide an [MCVE](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/whats-a-minimum-complete-verifiable-example-mcve-and-how-do-i-provide-it) so we can test it too?

Comment: No, everything else including physics has zero effect, only mouse movement. DPI and polling rate don't seem to affect it either. Unfortunately it isn't my project so id have to get permission to share any part of it, sorry.

Comment: I was hoping this may have been an issue seen before, and some general information about it was known. If not, no worries. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code I would say it's an issue of updating for every event including mouse axes events, which shouldn't cause an update. They should trigger a redraw flag which is handled by your timer event and redraw.